# How to parse out the end of a path in a unix shell script?

Tags: linux, unix, shell

I have a .sh unix shell script that receives as a parameter a path, say `/home/test/user1`.  So, in the variable `${1}`, that is the parameter.

I want to create a file whose name is based on the last part of that path, user1.  How can I parse that path to retrieve the last piece of the path?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [basename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename) command.

```
$ basename /home/test/user1
user1
```

**Edit:** (in response to your comment)

In a shell-script variable, you need backticks:

```
END_OF_PATH=`basename "${1}"`
```

Comment: Didn't know of this!  So I could just say END_OF_PATH=basename ${1}?

Comment: You need to quote the path variable since it may contain spaces: `"${1}"`.

Comment: When I do this, if I echo $END_OF_PATH I get exactly what I typed, not the result of the command.  The output is "basename /home/test/user1", not "user1".  Why?

Comment: @coffee: Wrong type of quote. Use backticks `\``, not single quotes `'`. Copy and paste the answer. You could also use `$(basename "${1}")` which is equivalent.

Comment: For completeness sake:  `dirname` is a 'dual' to basename, it cuts out the file, and leaves only the directory path to the file path provided.  Very useful, and way more robust than cooking up your own regex.